# D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found

Tags: android, android-guava, android-d8

After enabling D8 in my android project, I've started seeing these warnings:

```
/Users/yashasvi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar: D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper.<clinit>()`
/Users/yashasvi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar: D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `sun.misc.Unsafe com.google.common.cache.Striped64.getUnsafe()`
/Users/yashasvi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar: D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `sun.misc.Unsafe com.google.common.hash.LittleEndianByteArray$UnsafeByteArray.getUnsafe()`
/Users/yashasvi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar: D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper.<clinit>()`
/Users/yashasvi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar: D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `sun.misc.Unsafe com.google.common.cache.Striped64.getUnsafe()`
/Users/yashasvi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-android/b7e1c37f66ef193796ccd7ea6e80c2b05426182d/guava-27.0.1-android.jar: D8: Type `sun.misc.Unsafe` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `sun.misc.Unsafe com.google.common.hash.LittleEndianByteArray$UnsafeByteArray.getUnsafe()`
```

.

Project builds successfully but at runtime, I see these error logs and due to this, app functionality is affected.

```
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Object com.google.common.base.e.a(java.lang.Object)"
        at com.google.common.e.a.i$c.a(SourceFile:1464)
        at com.google.common.e.a.i$c.a(SourceFile:1453)
        at com.google.common.e.a.i$a.run(SourceFile:1408)
        at com.google.common.e.a.l$a.execute(SourceFile:456)
        at com.google.common.e.a.i$f.a(SourceFile:153)
        at com.google.common.e.a.i.a(SourceFile:1234)
```

I haven't been able to find anything useful on this after searching for a while. Please help.

And yes, I don't face this error at runtime if D8 is disabled and everything else remains same.

Comment: Do you use lambda in your code? It might cause some error. Take a look at this link https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3227

Comment: might be. let me check.

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep `sun.misc.Unsafe`:

```
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe
```

alternatively, a rule with `includedescriptorclasses` should keep it dynamically:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.common.**
```

in general:

- adding switch `-verbose` is quite helpful for writing ProGuard configuration rules.
- adding switch `-dontoptimize` can be used to disable all optimization, for a test.

just found [this](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2117):

> R8 now understands proguard specs in META-INF/proguard.

but unless this had been added, one has to add custom rules - instead of using consumer rules.

Answer (score 0):

In your project-proguard file. Please add this:

```
-keepnames class com.google.common.**

-keep class com.google.common.**

-dontwarn com.google.common.**
```

It seems to be a sort of bug. But sometimes when you using D8 it tend to renames class names or delete them altogether.

Comment: but this will increase will apk size,right? keeping everything in `com.google.common`

Comment: Slighty, you may not even notice the difference. If you using any model(POJO) class, add @keep before class name also.

Comment: D8 will still shrink your code tho, but will keep what's necessary

Comment: Have you tried my solution? You haven't given any feedback.